# qserialport crashes when called from slot

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, hardware

I am writing a gui in QT for controlling usb relays. I wrote a relay class which has turn on/off member functions. also wrote a custom widget which has radio buttons for controlling, a relay pointer, as well as a switchStatus() slot in which the relay turn on/off functions were called. The mainwindow has relay members. When I call the the ui->widget->switchStatus() from the mainwindow constructor, everything works fine, the relay can be turn on and off well. However, if I connect the radio button signal to switchStatus(), the program crashes whenever I click the radio button. It crashes at the line serialPort->write. But it's not about write, whatever code related to serialPort pointer it first come to will cause crash. even I want to get the port name or port address.

```
myWidget::myWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), m_ui(new Ui::Form)
{    status = 0;

    m_ui->setupUi(this);
    m_ui->statusIndicator->status = &status; // status in ui pointing to null before this

    m_ui->turnOffButton->setChecked(true);
    connect(m_ui->turnOnButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(switchStatus())); 
//crashes when click ratioButton, 
//compare to last line in the mainwindow construtor
    connect(m_ui->turnOffButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(switchStatus()));
}

void myWidget::switchStatus()
{
    qDebug() << "swithcing";
    if(status)
    {
        setStatus(false);
    }
    else
    {
        setStatus(true);
    }
    m_relay->switchStatus();

}


void relay::switchStatus()
{   if(status) turnOff();
    else turnOn();
}

bool relay::turnOn(){
    qDebug() << writeDataOn; // test if string is correct
    qDebug() << serialPort; // crashes whenever serialPort address is called
    const qint64 bytesWritten = serialPort->write(writeDataOn);
}


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    QList<QSerialPortInfo> infos = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
    qDebug() << infos[0].description();
    QSerialPort serialPort;
    serialPort.setPortName(infos[0].portName());
    serialPort.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    if (!serialPort.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        qDebug() << QObject::tr("Failed to open port %1, error: %2").arg(serialPort.portName()).arg(serialPort.error()) ;
    }
    ui->setupUi(this);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        relays[i].setRelayNumber(i);
        relays[i].setPort(&serialPort);
        relays[i].setStatus(relays[i].getRealStatus());
    }


    ui->widget->m_relay = relays;

    qDebug() << ui->widget->m_relay;
    qDebug() << ui->widget->m_relay->getPort();

    ui->widget->switchStatus(); // this line runs well
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your serial port a member of the MainWindow class. At the moment it is local to your constructor, so it is deallocated when the constructor finishes, hence the crashing. If you have declared a 'serialPort' member, you are hiding it by redeclaring it as a local scope variable inside the constructor.

Comment: thanks a lot. It works like a charm. I just have another question. If I don't use a pointer for serialPort, do I need to set its parent to be the mainwindow? my thought is no. The parent is only for dynamically allocated objects for preventing memory leak? am I right about this? thanks again